# quicksort printing comparison

Tags: java, quicksort

Here is my code from the quicksort partition method:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] array) 
{
doQuickSort(array, 0, random1.length - 1);

 }
 private static void doQuickSort(int[] array, int start, int end)
 {
int pivotPoint;

 if(start < end)
 {
   pivotPoint = partition(array, start, end);

    doQuickSort(array,start, pivotPoint - 1);

    doQuickSort(array, pivotPoint +1, end); 
    }


  }
 private static int partition(int[] array, int start, int end)
{
int pivotValue = array[start];
int endOfLeftList = start;
int mid = (start + end)/2;;
int compare = 0;
int swap = 0;

  for(int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++)
  {
   compare++;
   if(array[scan] < pivotValue)
   { 
     swap++;
     endOfLeftList++;
      swap(array, endOfLeftList, scan);
   }
  }

    System.out.println("\nComparisons: " + compare); 
    System.out.println("Swaps: " + swap);

  swap(array, start, endOfLeftList);

  return endOfLeftList;

}
```

With a randomly generated array, it seems no matter where i put the print statements, when i call the entire quicksort method it prints continuously like such:

```
 Array Before QuickSort:
 40 27 13 58 42 41 84 4 75 96 
 Comparisons: 1
 Swaps: 1

 Comparisons: 2
 Swaps: 2

 Comparisons: 3
 Swaps: 2

 Comparisons: 4
 Swaps: 2

 Comparisons: 5
 Swaps: 2

 Comparisons: 6
 Swaps: 2

 Comparisons: 7
 Swaps: 3

 Comparisons: 8
 Swaps: 3

 Comparisons: 9
 Swaps: 3

 Comparisons: 1
 Swaps: 0

 Comparisons: 2
 Swaps: 0

 Comparisons: 1
 Swaps: 1

 Comparisons: 1
 Swaps: 1

 Comparisons: 2
 Swaps: 1

 Comparisons: 3
 Swaps: 1

 Comparisons: 4
 Swaps: 1

 Comparisons: 5
 Swaps: 1

 Comparisons: 1
 Swaps: 1

 Comparisons: 2
 Swaps: 2

 Comparisons: 3
 Swaps: 2

 Comparisons: 1
 Swaps: 1

 Array After QuickSort:
 4 13 27 40 41 42 58 75 84 96
```

I must be overlooking something but I'm just not sure. I'm trying to get it to just print once, stating how many comparisons, how many swaps. I will edit with additional information if needed.

Comment: where do you call your `partition` method?

Comment: i call it in a 'doQuickSort' method, which is then called in the 'quickSort' method, as a normal Quicksort works.

Comment: please post those methods as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because for quicksorting you might be calling the `partition` method a lot of time until the array is sorted. So, to get the total counts only once and after the process is complete, you should do this :

Make these variables global:

```
int compare = 0;
int swap = 0;
```

and wherever your main sorting function is, just put these print statements after calling it:

```
System.out.println("\nComparisons: " + compare); 
System.out.println("Swaps: " + swap);
```

**EDIT**

So, as per your edited question you should've the print statements either inside your `quickSort` method like this:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] array) 
{
    doQuickSort(array, 0, random1.length - 1);
    System.out.println("\nComparisons: " + compare); 
    System.out.println("Swaps: " + swap);
}
```

or after wherever you call `quickSort` like this:

```
quickSort(someIntArray);
System.out.println("\nComparisons: " + compare); 
System.out.println("Swaps: " + swap);
```

Comment: If i put the statements inside the quickSort method, i would need to change all the parameters for each method, which does not work or get defined in the end. Could you elaborate?

Comment: you won't have to change any parameters, what parameters are you talking about?

Comment: also, kindly read the complete answer i.e, : Make these variables global:
`int compare = 0;`
`int swap = 0; `. By making global I mean move them out of the `partition` method to your class

Comment: Ok i see what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it print's the comparison each time is because you are using this function each time you need a partition, which for a quick-sort is many times.

If you want to only show the end then you should create a separate function that prints the number of comparisons

ex:

```
void printComparisons(int compare, int swap){
     System.out.println("\nComparisons: " + compare); 
     System.out.println("Swaps: " + swap);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it had little to no effect. If i call it anywhere other than the partition method(which has no difference than my initial problem), i need to change the parameters of every other method, which still doesn't work. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You should run it after your quicksort not in it.. quicksort is recursive so each time it runs itself it will run anything in it... so create a function similar to my example and run it in main after your quick-sort. To keep track of values you could make the integers global, but I hate doing that. Perhaps you could have quick-sort return an integer to count comparisons.